# Improving a question about a basic feature of a language that's new to me

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I know I shouldn't care about a few downvotes here and there, but I want to be a good SO user.  I've been a programmer for a few years, but I still consider myself beginnerish, and I'm totally new to PHP.  So my questions are basic, but I know how to research, and I put in time trying before I ask anything.

[Does filtering a PHP array cause numbers to skip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971734/does-filtering-a-php-array-cause-numbers-to-skip)

I thought my question was good.  I put time into putting it together, and I read the docs that eventually answered my question, but coming from a Python background I didn't understand that in PHP, the array keys correspond to the number placement in the array.  I guess it makes sense, but it doesn't work that way in Python.

I think my question could be helpful to a future user (although I think it could have a better title; that was the best I could do.  Open to improvements.)

What should I do to improve?  Honestly, half the time I'm reluctant to even post here, even though I find it an amazing resource (and a time-suck, but that's my own problem).

Comment: Unless you have deleted questions I'm not seeing, I only see a single recent downvote... nothing to worry about.

Comment: I know I'm overreacting.  It just bugs me when I get a downvote with no given reason why (which I understand has been discussed to death and I'm not re-opening now)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the one downvote. Almost all of your questions seem to be well-recieved; you're doing fine.

You're new the language and you've explained what you're doing and what's happening clearly and succinctly. You seem to have done your homework. It looks like a perfectly reasonable question. That said, I can offer a small piece of advice.

For a question like this, you've included some irrelevant details. You're talking maybe a bit too specifically about your own situation: "I have code that starts with a list of articles." Eh, doesn't matter what your particular data is; you've got an array of THINGS that you're filtering by some property of the things. Distill that down. Get rid of anything in the code that doesn't directly contribute to the problem.* (Checking for an empty array, in your case.) Type up some dummy data and produce [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the behavior you're seeing that doesn't include *any* unnecessary pieces.

In this context, where you're new to the language and confused by built-in behavior, I'd consider that solid proof that you've exhausted all your resources in figuring out what's going on. In order to produce that example code, you're going to have to use every bit of understanding that you have to make sure you're exactly reproducing the situation from your real code, and I believe that understanding will shine through in your post. (That's if you don't manage to solve it yourself in the process, which often happens.)

---

*And don't say "well, I don't know what contributes to the problem", because that *does* mean that you didn't do your homework.

Comment: Well, part of the extraneous details was just to make the variables make sense, but I see what you're saying.  I did delete a lot--the actual code I cut and pasted from is much longer.  I don't know what your addendum is referring to, though; where did I say that?

Comment: No, you didn't; sorry if I gave you the impression I thought you did. I wrote that because another person in a similar situation to yours, who reads this Meta question, might say it.

Comment: Gotcha--good advice!